# Create a public folder in Skydrive Pro

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive

I'm getting started with the SkyDrive Pro (via Office 365 sub) and am trying to replicate something that's very easy to do in GoogleDocs - create a folder where any files held within become public and visible to anyone without required any authentication on the part of the viewer.

Out of the box dialogs don't show the path but really has to be a way, right?